# How do I properly set up geth to make JSON RPC calls

Tags: installation, ethereum, go-ethereum

I installed Geth in order to fire JSON RPC calls to the ethereum test net Goerli. I followed the getting started tutorial [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started/geth-and-clef). I followed the instructions and did the following:

1. Generated a new account (wallet address) by calling `clef newaccount --keystore <my_local_dir>/keystore`
2. Started clef on Goerli (chain ID is 5) and used the newly generated keys by pointing to the keystore dir `clef --keystore <my_local_dir>/keystore --configdir <my_local_dir>/clef --chainid 5`
3. Started geth to sync with nodes by calling `geth --datadir <my_local_dir> --signer=<my_local_dir>/clef/clef.ipc --goerli --syncmode snap --http`
4. Attached to running node by calling `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545`. Although, I believe this step can be skipped, since I am trying to fire JSON RPC requests
5. Fired the request through postman - the generated curl command is the following:

```
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_getBalance",
    "params": ["0x631e9b031b16b18172a2b9d66c3668a68a668d20", "latest"],
    "id": 1
}'
```

What could I possible be doing wrong? I see the account does have ether ([balance](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x631e9b031b16b18172a2b9d66c3668a68a668d20)), but I keep getting 0 as a result of my call:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": "0x0"
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research and talking with colleagues, I believe I now know why I wasn't able to retrieve blockchain data. It is only available once the node is fully synced:

`Client execution will initiate its core functions, chosen endpoints, and start looking for peers. After successfully discovering peers, the client starts synchronization. Current blockchain data will be available once the client is successfully synced to the current state.`

This can be found in the last paragraph [here](https://ethereum.org/ca/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/run-a-node/#starting-the-execution-client).

So the issue wasn't a failed installation or setup, but rather unsynced client.